# Changing a property file in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am having a project that is being build by Jenkins. The project uses the specific URL that has been mentioned in a properties file.

The property file has to be updated by the Jenkins with the specific URL that i provide during the course of build process.

The property file would have only one field:

```
URL=https://www.example.com/
```

What do you think? How can this be done efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this in Jenkins is executing a command in the terminal.

After your build is successful, there's an option for "**execute batch**" and then go to the path of your properties file by using command 
**cd (path_of properties_file)** and this path must be your Jenkins workspace path.Then use the command "**sed**". This command helps us to replace the existing value.This sed command is specific to unix.

The basic example for sed command is 
**sed 's/pattern/replace_string/' file**

Comment: What is the command for windows? The Jenkins runs in windows environment.

Comment: This is the command fart "FILE_PATH" oldText newText. I'm not sure this works or not. I'm a Linux user but you can try this. @BalajiVignesh